# Timestamp overlay added video has some frames which have the same PTS

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I added timestamp overlay to an mp4 video by this command

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -vf "drawtext=x=(w-(max_glyph_w*13))/2: y=H-h/10:fontcolor=white:fontsize=h/14:box=1:boxcolor=0x000000AA:text='%{pts\\:hms}'" -y -vsync 0 output.mkv
```

The problem is the output video didn't preserve the PTS as the original video, and instead, a lot of frames have the same PTS which was weird.

For example, to get the PTS of the video, I used `ffprobe -select_streams v -show_packets tmp_timestamp.mkv | grep pts_time`, and the results were

```
pts_time=0.000000
pts_time=0.000000
pts_time=0.251000
pts_time=0.251000
pts_time=0.251000
pts_time=0.251000
pts_time=0.502000
pts_time=0.502000
pts_time=1.004000
pts_time=1.004000
pts_time=1.004000
pts_time=1.004000
pts_time=1.004000
pts_time=1.004000
pts_time=1.255000
pts_time=1.255000
pts_time=1.255000
pts_time=1.506000
pts_time=1.506000
pts_time=1.506000
pts_time=1.506000
pts_time=1.506000
pts_time=1.506000
pts_time=1.506000
pts_time=1.506000
pts_time=1.506000
pts_time=1.506000
pts_time=1.506000
pts_time=1.506000
pts_time=1.757000
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of video. Most files have really poor metadata, and players have just been written to handle it the best as possible.